# Maven project license report on jars

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to use maven to build a report that will output the licenses for the jars I am using in a project. I have come across other posts on here that point in the right direction using the maven project report plugin, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the commands correctly.

Like I've been trying to use commands like the following,

```
mvn project-info-reports:license

mvn project-info-reports:dependencies

mvn site

mvn site project-info-reports:license
```

but I'm not having much luck getting a report like the following - [Project Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/dependencies.html).

The site command created a bunch of information in the target folder but none have license information. I'm relatively new to maven so if someone could show me a quick example of how I should be doing this it would be very much appreciated, as I can't seem to find an example online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executing `mvn site` or `mvn project-info-reports:dependencies` command generates the report you want. It is located in `project-folder/target/site/dependencies.html`. ( I am using maven 3.5.2)

Comment: Thank you, I'm having an issue where this command fails on one of the plugins so can't get it to generate a proper report. I can run "mvn project-info-reports:license does" fine but not sure if this actually generates anything. Can that command also be used to generate reports on its own?

Comment: @seanleroy use `mvn project-info-reports:dependencies`. The report generated is in the same path mentioned in the answer

Comment: @miskender thanks for details. it helped me to generate the report